# Issue when installing pycrypto

Tags: python, pycrypto

I am attempting to install pycrypto I have followed multiple other threads, currently I have upgraded pip, setuptools and installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. However I am still getting errors when running the setup. I am installing pycrypto via pip. I need to install it on python 3.6.5. Full installation log https://hastebin.com/unenukecil.php

Comment: And the error you're getting is?

Comment: It still shows that Visual Studio 14.0 is not installed

Comment: @Torxed The hastebin link is the error

Comment: @Agile_Eagle Well ware, but in 2 years when that site shuts down, it would be neat if there's a record **in the actual question** what the error was. There's nothing more annoying then coming back to a question a year or two later, and there's dead links to both the question and the answer :P

Comment: @Torxed the error is too big to fix on the site

Comment: @Agile_Eagle are you sure? Because I was getting a different error then I installed Visual Studio and the error changed to the above error

Comment: @Ogden It really isn't. You don't need that entire log to determine the problem. For instance, all of the "copying X -> Y" is extremely redundant. The build command `C:\...\cl.exe`, the errors and the exit statuses are all you really need. And it fits on this site perfectly as long as you put it in a code block so it doesn't become a never ending wall of text (tex blocks are scrollable block of indentation free blocks). Anyway, what Agile says seams pretty spot on. Look at the compiler path, it probably can't handle the syntax used to compile the lib for instance.